# In Newton's Wake; why are (certain) terraforming machines called Darwin-Gosse machines?

Tags: newtons-wake

In Ken MacLeod's book *Newton's Wake*, machines called Darwin-Gosse machines are used for terraforming biospheres of planets.

Naming a terraforming machine after Darwin seems pretty appropriate, but that's the first time I'd heard the name Gosse.

In reading up on [Philip Henry Gosse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Henry_Gosse#Works) (who seems more likely than [Jean-Pierre Gosse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Gosse) to be the origin of the machine name,) I'm not seeing much in the way of groundbreaking ecological or genetic work that would lend itself to having a terraforming machine named after him.

Unless the point of his inclusion in the name is to emphasize the importance of the marine aspect of terraforming, relating to his work in aquariums.

Does anyone know why MacLeod picked Gosse?

Comment: Gosse is probably most famous for his argument that God laid down fossils just to make the Earth look old. Don't the Darwin-Gosse machines also lay down false fossil records?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez In the book the reference to a fake fossil record is one created by the ship itself, not the terraforming machines.

Comment: @DavidW Fair enough!

Answer (score 5):

Gosse wrote a book **Omphalos: an attempt to untie the geological knot**, in which he argued that God created the world with deliberate signs of a history that never really occurred (Omphalos means navel - Adam's navel suggested a birth that hadn't happened).  The terraforming machine give similar false indications of a past that hadn't happened (evolving the biosphere virtually and making that final result real).

From the [Gosse book](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/39910/39910-h/39910-h.htm)

> It is not necessary,—at least it does not seem so to me,—that all the
> members of this mighty commonwealth should have an actual, a
> diachronic existence; anymore than that, in the creation of a man, his
> fœtal, infantile, and adolescent stages should have an actual,
> diachronic existence, though these are essential to his normal
> life-history. Nor would their diachronism be more certainly inferrible
> from the physical traces of them, in the one case than in the other.
> In the newly-created Man, the proofs of successive processes requiring
> time, in the skin, hairs, nails, bones, &c. could in no respect be
> distinguished from the like proofs in a Man of to-day;[Pg 347] yet the
> developments to which they respectively testify are widely different
> from each other, so far as regards the element of time.

From Newton's Wake (thanks to @DavidW):

> the ship was equipped with what are called Darwin-Gosse machines. They
> are capable of evolving and entire biosphere in virtual space, and
> creating the result.

This seems very likely to be the reason that MacLeod chose that name.

Comment: This is not correct; the Darwin-Gosse machines may have created the biosphere, but the fake fossil record was created by the _ship_: "the ship was equipped with what are called Darwin-Gosse machines.  They are capable of evolving and entire biosphere in virtual space, and creating the result.  **The ship's own capabilities well exceeded that.  It reshaped Eurydice's lithosphere.  It laid down new strata.  It created the fossil record.**"

Comment: Thank you.  I'll fix